# Glassfish - Simultaneous connections from same client

Tags: multithreading, request, glassfish

I'm building a application that must process up to 300 requests from one client.

I've tried all the configurations suggested on this link: [Glassfish Thread Pool, Acceptor Threads, HTTP Max Connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33096017/glassfish-thread-pool-acceptor-threads-http-max-connections) , but during my tests I could only get 5 requests being processed at the same time per host (If I try with 2 hosts, the servers will process 10 requests. 3 hosts, 15 request and so on...).

**My question is**: Which configuration do I need to change so glassfish can process more than 5 request at a time per client?

Obs: I'm using glassfish 4.1

Comment: It surprises me how refreshing a good night of sleep can be! After doing another tests today, I figured out that the problem was related to the browser. Apparently firefox was "holding" the 6th request until the 1th had finished. When I did the request from the server (using java threads), I could finally see 300 threads being created.

Comment: The standard for browsers, was 2 connections for each host. Good to know that Glassfish was not the problem.

Comment: @ThiagoCarvalho can u tell me your server configuration...actually I need to implement same but my cpu usages is showing 100%...so what configuration can help me